# \int does not work on my LyX

Tags: fonts, lyx

Just starting to use LaTeX to type up my homework. I am doing differential equations right now and I have to type in an integral symbol.

However when I do that, and try to make a DVI, LyX gives me an error (both when producing pdf and dvi). The error is following:

```
MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: Not all fonts could be loaded. See 'File->Document Properties', for details.
Data: 
Source: Programs\MiKTeX\Yap\MFC\DviDoc.cpp
Line: 636
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium Edition, 64-bit (build 7600)
SystemAdmin: no
PowerUser: no
Root0: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root3: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
```

Also a very similar error occurs when I try to change text into bold. I am assuming I am missing some sort of font files (since that's what the error refers to). Anyways, let me know how I can fix this.

Comment: Umm I dont know what I did, but I went to MikTex folder and "updated and refreshed" something and .. everything is working now. Wierd.

Comment: If you leave your comment as an answer below and then "accept" it by ticking the green checkbox next to the answer, this will help people in the future searching for a solution to the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm I dont know what I did, but I went to MikTex folder and "updated and refreshed" something and .. everything is working now. Wierd

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu installing texlive-latex-extra solved the problem for me.